# Standard brownian motion 4

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ be two independent standard Brownian motions, and for each time $t$ let $F_t$ be the $σ$−algebra consisting of all events determined by the paths $(X_s)_{s≤t}$ and $(Y_s)_{s≤t}$

(a) What is $P \{X_3 > X_2 + X_1 + 1\}$?

(b) What is $P \{X_t < 2Y_t + 1 \text{ for all } t ≤ 1\}$?

I am confused with part (a). How should i proceed with it , 
one solution = $P\{X_3 - X_2 - X_1 > 1\} = P\{\sqrt{3}\cdot X_1-\sqrt{2}\cdot X_1-X_1 >1\}$. But not sure if this approach is correct. Part(b) i have no clue?

Comment: Since $X_3-X_2-X_1$ is still Gaussian, you need only calculate the variance.

Comment: For (b), note that $X_t-2Y_t =_d \sqrt{5} X_t$ and $\sup_{0\le s\le t}X_s =_d |X_t|$.

Comment: What is the issue with my approach in part(a)

Comment: Even though $X_2 =_d \sqrt{2} X_1$, how can you deduce that $(X_2,X_1) =_d (\sqrt{2}X_1,X_1)$ ?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand that?

Comment: "the deduce part" i don't understand the notations.

Comment: i guess that you thought $X_3 =_d \sqrt{3}X_1$ and $X_2 =_d \sqrt{2}X_1$ could imply $X_3-X_2-X_1 =_d (\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}-1)X_1$. But, one should be careful when operations are performed at both sides of some \emph{equation in distribution}.

Comment: sorry, i mean "equal in distribution" by "=_d"

Answer (score 2):

Hint For b): consider $Z_t=\frac {X_t-2Y_t} {\sqrt 5}$. Then $\{Z_t\}$ is a standard Brownian motion. So the required probability is $P\{Z_t < \frac 1 { \sqrt 5} \,\text {for}\,  t \leq 1\}$.Do you know what this probability is?

Your answer to a) is wrong because $X_3-X_2-X_1$ does not have the same distribution as $\sqrt 3 X_1-\sqrt 2 X_1-X_1$. In fact the former is normal with mean $0$ and variance $2$ whereas the latter is normal with mean $0$ and variance $(\sqrt 3 -\sqrt 2 -1)^{2}$. [$X_3-X_2$ and $X_1$ are independent normal variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$ each so their difference is normal with mean $0$ and variance $2$. This also tells you how to answer part a)].

Comment: Shouldnt it be P{Zt < 1/sqrt(5) for t <= 1}.

Comment: @smstud You are right.

Comment: and then for calculating this probability, should i use reflection principle?

Comment: @smstud Exactly.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the issue with my solution for part (a)?

Comment: @smstud I have explained it in my answer now

Comment: Let (Sn)n≥0 be a simple random walk on the integers, that is, Sn =
Pn
i=1 ξi where ξ1, ξ2, · · · are
independent, identically distributed random variables with distribution
P{ξi = +1} = P{ξi = −1} =
1
2
.
(A) Let A ≥ 2 be an integer larger than 1, and let T be the first time n ≥ 1 that the random walk
either returns to 0 or hits either +A or −A. That is, T = min(τ, νA) where τ = min{n ≥ 1 : Sn =
0} and νA = min{n ≥ 1 : |Sn| = A}. What is ET?
(B) What is P{max0≤m≤12 Sm ≥ 6 and S12 = 4}?
I have solved part(a) using Doobs's identity, can you give any clue in solving part (B).

Comment: @smstud If you ask new questions in comments it may not be accessed by many. Please ask new question.